# Xcode 'Use of undeclared identifier' error but variable exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am adding tracking to an xcode project. In my ViewController.m I get an error for 'Use of undeclared identifier' for a variable that I have declared already.

in ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.analyticsViewEventBundle = [[AnalyticsController sharedAnalyticsController] publishScreenLoadStartedWithScreenName:AnalyticsControllerScreenName_ScreenStyle existingViewEventBundle:self.analyticsViewEventBundle];
}
```

The above generates `use of undeclared identifier 'AnalyticsControllerScreenName_ScreenStyle'`. However, if I change that piece to `AnalyticsControllerScreenName_MyStore` there is no error.

If I search XCode I see that both lines appear next to each other in the correct AnalyticsController.m file. Here is an example:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, AnalyticsControllerScreenName) {
    AnalyticsControllerScreenName_MyStore, 
    AnalyticsControllerScreenName_ScreenStyle,               
};
```

Is there something extra I need to do to be able to use `AnalyticsControllerScreenName_ScreenStyle`?

**UPDATE:**

I removed the comma but still get the error.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, AnalyticsControllerScreenName) {
    AnalyticsControllerScreenName_MyStore, 
    AnalyticsControllerScreenName_ScreenStyle               
};
```

**UPDATE:**
The problem ended up being that two copies of my AnalyticsController were loaded into the project somehow and the one not visible in the Target navigator was the one being used. I deleted that file, cleaned and built and everything worked as expected after that.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comma after AnalyticsControllerScreenName_ScreenStyle.

Try this, it worked for me

```
typedef enum{
    AnalyticsControllerScreenName_MyStore, 
    AnalyticsControllerScreenName_ScreenStyle               
} AnalyticsControllerScreenName;
```

Comment: I tried removing the comma and there was no difference. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I tried that solution and get the same error. I can highlight the function in the ViewController and jump to definition and it goes to the correct line in the AnalyticsController. but still that option doesn't come up for autocomplete and still shows the same error.

Comment: Seems like the error is in the header file that contains this enum. Because I used yours and it did compile successfully.

Comment: It turns out the function is referencing a version of my AnalyticsController that is not in the Target. So if I entered the value that works then Jump to that definition it brought up this different file than where I had made my edits with the new value. I'm still not sure why there are two files and how to get the project to reference the file in the Target.

Comment: Remove it then add it again. Clean your build and try again.

Comment: Great! Good you got the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Your enumeration is being defined as

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, AnalyticsControllerScreenName) {
    AnalyticsControllerScreenName_MyStore, 
    AnalyticsControllerScreenName_ScreenStyle,               
};
```

The problem is that the comma after `AnalyticsControllerScreenName_ScreenStyle` tells the compiler that another element is going to be specified, but you didn't provide one. To fix this, do:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, AnalyticsControllerScreenName) {
    AnalyticsControllerScreenName_MyStore, 
    AnalyticsControllerScreenName_ScreenStyle               
};
```

Comment: I made the change you suggest but still get the same error. Anything else I should try?

Comment: It has been legal to add an extra comma at the end of an enumeration list for a long time.